# Handling JSON Response With Django

Tags: json, django, python-3.5

Django 1.9 Python3.5

I am using tastypie to consume an external api

I am creating a class to handle the json response from a restful api. I know the data types coming back from the api but do not know how to declare a few of them.

This is how I declare them in Golang

```
    PosterPath       string  `json:"poster_path"`
    Adult            bool    `json:"adult"`
    Overview         string  `json:"overview"`
    ReleaseDate      string  `json:"release_date"`
    GenreIds         []int   `json:"genre_ids"`
    Id               int     `json:"id"`
    OriginalTitle    string  `json:"original_title"`
    OriginalLanguage string  `json:"original_language"`
    Title            string  `json:"title"`
    BackdropPath     string  `json:"backdrop_path"`
    Popularity       float64 `json:"popularity"`
    VoteCount        int     `json:"vote_count"`
    Video            bool    `json:"video"`
    VoteAverage      float64 `json:"vote_average"`
```

From my understanding this is how I should declare them with DJjango

```
class Movies(Resource):
    PosterPath = fields.URLField(attribute='poster_path')
    Adult = fields.BooleanField(attribute='adult')
    Overview = fields.CharField(attribute='overview')
    ReleaseDate = fields.CharField(attribute='release_date')
    GenreIds = fields.**Array of Ints**(attribute='genre_ids')
    Id = fields.IntegerField(attribute='id')
    OriginalTitle = fields.CharField(attribute='original_title')
    OriginalLanguage = fields.CharField(attribute='original_language')
    Title = fields.CharField(attribute='title')
    BackdropPath = fields.URLField(attribute='backdrop_path')
    Popularity = fields.DecimalField(attribute='popularity')
    VoteCount = fields.IntegerField(attribute='vote_count')
    Video = fields.BooleanField(attribute='video')
    VoteAverage = fields.DecimalField(attribute='vote_average')
```

This field

```
GenreIds = fields.**Array of Ints**(attribute='genre_ids')
```

It is an array of ints. What is the correct way to handle the json of this type? It looks like this,

```
"genre_ids": [
        18,
        10402
      ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Postgres specific [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) in django. Also you may transform resceived array to string and store it in CommaSeparatedIntegerField which is db agnostic.

PS: I believe you are using models in wrong way. Field classes should be accessed via '**models**' module, but not '**fileds**' module (i.e. 
**models.BooleanField** instead of 
**fields.BooleanField**)

Comment: I am using tastypie. I am not building  model I am using an external api for a json response. Also is ArrayField dynamic in size? Is there no way to do a ListField?

Comment: Yes, the ArrayField is dynamic. Initialize as a list `times = ArrayField(models.DateTimeField(), default=list)` and append to it like you normally would.